# why app config lost,when akka used mvn package jar and load by typesafe factory?

Tags: java, configuration, akka, maven-shade-plugin, typesafe-config

guys.
When i was packaging akka app into jar, i used mvn plugin named maven-shade-plugin.
The application.conf and stat.conf were put in to classes filefolder,
and used Main.class to load it, java code on Main.class as follows:

```
Config appConfig = ConfigFactory
                .parseString( "akka.remote.netty.tcp.port=" + args[i] )
                .withFallback(
                        ConfigFactory.parseString( "akka.cluster.roles = [engine]" ) )
                .withFallback( com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.load( "stats" ) );
```

My pom.xml plugins as follows:

```
<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <includes>
                                <include>*:*</include>
                            </includes>
                        </artifactSet>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>stats.conf</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>akka.conf</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.*.ad.engine.akka.Main</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

when i used mvn command to run app, it works :

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.*.ad.engine.akka.Main" -Dexec.args="2551 2552"
```

And i have a problem, the akka default configuration were lost when i used packaged jar and used java -jar to run the same app, the default config seems like be override by null and app can't run normally...
Please help me to solve the problems, or help me to figure out the error points.
thx bro.

Comment: as u think.i change a way to package jar with config : <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer"><resource>reference.conf</resource></transformer>  and rename conf to akka.conf and stats.conf . it works! thank u,my princess.

Comment: ref link : http://akka-user.narkive.com/LdLPLicZ/reference-conf-conflicts-in-fat-jar-i-think